# Multiple inputs type date put into a href using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Can someone help me? I want to use `<input type="date">` and insert the value inserted into `<a href="">` using jQuery. I have tried my best but I can't solve it please help.

HTML markup:

```
    <input type="date" class="inpDate" value="">
    <input type="date" class="inpDate" value="">
    <a href="" id="getDate">Search</a>
```

Script code :

```
<script>
$(".inpDate").on("keyup",function(e){

  if(e. keyCode === 13){
    var address     = $('#getDate').attr('href');
    window.location = address;
  } 

  $('#getDate').attr("href","?page=d_jurnal_laporan/&date1="+$(".inpDate").val()+"&date2="+$(this).val());
})
</script>
```

Notes:

Actually it works if the input type is text, but here I want to make the input type date, and here I do more than one input

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: trying to move input type date to a href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are multiple targets with same class, you have to use `$(".inpDate")[0].value` and `$(".inpDate")[1].value` **OR** `$("inpDate:nth-child(1)").val()` and `$("inpDate:nth-child(2)").val()` combination.

**Edit**

`keyup` works only for key events. For the calender pick event this wont trigger. For that use `change` event rather than `keyup` so that it triggers for both input methods.

```js
$(".inpDate").on("change",function(e){
    if(e. keyCode === 13){
        var address     = $('#getDate').attr('href');
        window.location = address;
    }
    const url = "?page=d_jurnal_laporan/&date1=" + $(".inpDate:nth-child(1)").val()+"&date2="+$(".inpDate:nth-child(2)").val();
    console.log(url);
    $('#getDate').attr("href", url);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" class="inpDate" value="">
<input type="date" class="inpDate" value="">
<a href="" id="getDate">Search</a>
```

Comment: I m sorry, the previous question was wrong, the input type should be date not text, and I've tried it doesn't work

Comment: @RimeldaPratama its actually working. Can you check the above fiddle? I have updated my solution.

Comment: i have tried several times, and i tried a new file and copy it it doesn't work, it just goes back to the start page it doesn't go into a href

Comment: @RimeldaPratama See the updated answer now. `keyup` works only for keyboard inputs. To trigger for the calerder picker input, ypu have to use `change` event. Check the updated fiddle now.